# How does one specify in slurm to send e-mail when a single job finishes and not when each slurm array task finishes?

Tags: slurm

I was running lots of jobs in slurm with sbatch as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#SBATCH --job-name=Python
#SBATCH --array=1-200
#SBATCH --mem=4000
#SBATCH --time=0-18:20
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my_mail@yahoo.com
```

however, what seems to be happening is that slurm is sending me an e-mail for each array. However, I did not want slurm to do that, I only want me to send me an e-mail when all the slurm array have finishes (or failed) running. i.e. when a specific job (and ALL its job arrays are done). Is that possible to do in slurm?

I was reading the documentation and it says the following under `--mail-type=<type>`:

> Unless the ARRAY_TASKS option is specified, mail notifications on job
>   BEGIN, END and FAIL apply to a job array as a whole rather than
>   generating individual email messages for each task in the job array.

so might the problem be that I am using `ALL` instead of `BEGIN`,`END` or `FAIL`? I am honestly just interested when all the job arrays are done running even if a single fails its ok.

Comment: What version of Slurm are you running? The behaviour has changed in 15.08.0pre3

Comment: @damienfrancois how do I check the version?

Comment: `scontrol version`

Comment: @damienfrancois my slurm version seems to be: `slurm 16.05.4`

Comment: Can you try with `BEGIN,END,FAIL` rather than `ALL`, which also includes `REQUEUE`, and `STAGE_OUT`?

Comment: sorry @damienfrancois I somehow forgot about it due to chaos in life...but I think your right that should work. Docs: `Unless the ARRAY_TASKS option is specified, mail notifications on job BEGIN, END and FAIL apply to a job array as a whole rather than generating individual email messages for each task in the job array.` So I assume that should work, i.e. just doing END. I will try it now and report.

Answer (score 2):

The document:

--mail-type=

...
Unless the ARRAY_TASKS option is specified, mail notifications on job BEGIN, END and FAIL apply to a job array as a whole rather than generating individual email messages for each task in the job array.
...

https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

Hope this answers your question.